# Why does __mro__ not show up in dir(MyClass)?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

print MyClass.__mro__
print dir(MyClass)
```

Output:

```
(<class '__main__.MyClass'>, <type 'object'>)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

Why is `__mro__` not listed with `dir()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Python documentation:

> Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an
>   interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For
>   example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the
>   argument is a class.

`__mro__` is a read-only attribute that's used to determine method resolution in case your class inherits from multiple base classes. If you wish to customize this behavior, you should use a metaclass (a special kind of object whose purpose is to create class instances) which overrides the `mro()` method. `__mro__` is left unchanged in any case.

Comment: But that same documentation states that: "If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.". It's definitely confusing.

Comment: *Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt* - it's not intended as a tool for absolute completeness. I admit it seems weird.

Comment: When studying how Python works, a more complete *dir()* would  be nice.  However, when just using Python classes and instances, we usually want to see what data and services are provided rather than how they are implemented.  So, weird as it is, everyday practicality beats dir-must-show-all-details purity.

Answer (score 28):

I was recently wondering the same thing. I was looking for an answer more in line with "What about Python's implementation causes `mro`/`__mro__` not to be listed in `dir`? And what can I trust `dir` to list?" than simply "How does Python's documentation justify the non-inclusion of `mro` in `dir`?" I don't like it when my expectation of a programming language's behavior does not match it's actual behavior because it means my understanding of the language is incorrect -- unless it's just a bug like `urllib2.escape`. So I dug around a little bit, until I figured out the answer.

The line adolfopa quoted from the documentation in the comments above is a good one for explaining the behavior of dir.

> "If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases."

What does this mean? `dir` recursively gathers attributes from a class's `__dict__` and each of its superclasses' `__dict__`.

```
set(dir(object)) == set(dict(object.__dict__).keys() #True



class A(object):
    ...

class B(object):
    ...

class C(B):
    ...

class D(C,A):
    ...

set(dir(D)) == set(D.__dict__.keys()) + set(C.__dict__.keys()) \
   + set(B.__dict__.keys()) + set(A.__dict__.keys()) \
   + set(object.__dict__.keys()) #True
```

The reason `dir(object)` does not list `__mro__`/`mro` is that they are not attributes of object. They are attributes of `type`. Every class that doesn't define it's own `__metaclass__` is an instance of `type`. Most metaclasses subclass `type`. Instances of such metaclasses are likewise instances of type. `MyClass.__mro__` is the same as `type.__getattribute__(MyClass,'__mro__')`.

The way Python implements classes necessarily creates a slight anomaly with respect to how dir works.

Typically, `dir(MyClass) == dir(MyClass(*requiredparameters)) #True`.

However, `dir(type) == dir(type(*requiredparameters)) #False`, but the only way this could possibly be otherwise was if `type.__dict__` and `dir` were the same. This is, quite self-evidently, not the purpose of `dir`.

But wait! `dir` is created by a recursive sum, why can't we just change the final piece of it so that `dir(object)` is no longer just `object.__dict__.keys()` but rather it becomes `object.__dict__.keys() + type.__dict__.keys()`. That way, it would have `mro`/`__mro__` and all of the other attributes that the class object has? Ah, but those would be attributes of the class object, not the class. Well, what is the difference?

Consider

```
list.__mro__ #(<type 'list'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Whereas

```
[].__mro__
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

Now, we are in a good place to answer what we can count on `dir` to list and what we can count on `dir` to not list. The simple answer is the one we already covered. It lists all the keys in the class's `__dict__` plus all the keys in each of its superclasses' `__dict__`'s, recursively. For an instance, it also includes all the parameter's in the instance's `__dict__`. To fill in the negative space, it doesn't list anything defined in `__getattr__` or in anything in `__getattribute__` if it isn't also in the `__dict__`. It also doesn't list any attributes of the type/metatype.

---

One other thing that I feel I should point out: Dan's answer, which is the accepted answer at the time I am writing this, contains information that is inaccurate or at least misleading.

Attributes of built in objects cannot be set, so in a sense, `type.__mro__` is 'read-only,' but only in the same way that `list.append` is or `type.mro` is, for that matter.

`MyClass.__mro__ = "Hello world!"` does not cause an error. It simply does not affect the method resolution order defined in `type`. So it may not have the effect you were expecting if you were attempting to modify that behavior . (What it does do is cause `MyClass(*requiredparameters).__mro__` to be `"Hello World!"` which should have been what you would have expected, since this is how defining attributes of classes works in python.) You can also override `__mro__` when you are sub-classing type to create a metaclass. If you don't override it, it is inherited, just like anything else that you don't override. (If you are creating a metaclass that isn't a subclass of type and that isn't a function that returns an instance of type, presumably, you already know exactly what you are doing well enough that you aren't worrying about this, but `__mro__` would not be inherited since your not subclassing `type`)

According to the docs (describing the behavior of super):

> The __mro__ attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order used by both getattr() and super(). The attribute is dynamic and can change whenever the inheritance hierarchy is updated.

So directly modifying `__mro__` should behave as you would expect, in much the same way that modifying `mro` would. However, it's typically easier to get the behavior you want by overriding the function. (Think about what you need to do to handle subclassing properly.)

Comment: This part seems wrong: "doesn't list the keys of any attributes of the instance ... Anything that belongs to just one of them, doesn't get returned."  If I do: `class K(object): pass` and `inst=K()` and `dir(inst)` and then `inst.attr=1` and another `dir(inst)`, `attr` appears in the second `dir` output (in both 2.7.5 and 3.2.5).  Presumably you mean to restrict this discussion to `dir(K)` and not `dir(inst)`?

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I'll make the correction.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and points to some of the "cruft" of Python!  I wholly agree with the sentiment _I don't like it when my expectation of a programming language's behavior does not match it's actual behavior because it means my understanding of the language is incorrect_!!  I argue that _not understanding the language leads to bad code_! I know that Python is 32+ years old, and if folks started again, these things might be fixed.  But it seems that fixing cognitive dissonance is low on the priorities of core devs...