# How to find hidden attributes of Python objects? (attributes that don't appear in the dir(obj) list)

Tags: python, reflection

I'm using IPython.

I declared a simple class `MyClass(object)`, and in the console, when using the name MyClass, after the `dot` operator, i hit `Tab`.

One of the first suggestions i got was `mro`, meaning `MyClass.mro`. I hit enter, and the output i get is:

```
> <function mro>
```

Now i didn't define this method, and of course it returns the method resolution order of my class.

This method doesn't appear in the list returned by `dir(MyClass)`, and so here comes my question:

How would I find any other such *hidden* features of classes or other objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \_\_mro\_\_ not show up in dir(MyClass)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663514/why-does-mro-not-show-up-in-dirmyclass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dir()` does not try to provide a complete output, just a reasonable approximation that is useful in the interactive interpreter.

The reason for `dir` to *not* include `__mro__` and `mro` in the output can be found in the source code, under [`Objects/object.c` at line 1812](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Objects/object.c#l1812):

```c
/* Helper for PyObject_Dir of type objects: returns __dict__ and __bases__.
   We deliberately don't suck up its __class__, as methods belonging to the
   metaclass would probably be more confusing than helpful.
*/
static PyObject *
_specialized_dir_type(PyObject *obj)
```

And turns out that the `mro` method and the `__mro__` attribute are actually attributes of the *metaclass*, i.e. of `type`:

```
>>> '__mro__' in object.__dict__
False
>>> '__mro__' in type.__dict__
True
>>> 'mro' in object.__dict__
False
>>> 'mro' in type.__dict__
True
```

Hence they are not shown in the output of `dir`. Whether this is sensible or not depends. I believe most of the time you really do *not* want to see what the metaclass defines, since they are internals of the metaclass.

---

As explained in the documentation for [dir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) you can customize its output defining a `__dir__` method. However this applies to the *instances* of the class:

```
class A(object):
  def __dir__(self):
    return ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(dir(A()), dir(A))
```

Output:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__'])
```

If you want to customize also the output of `dir(A)` you have to use a custom metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
  def __dir__(self):
    return ['a', 'b', 'c']


class A(object, metaclass=MyMeta):
  # __metaclass__ = MyMeta   # in python 2

  def __dir__(self):
    return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


print(dir(A()), dir(A))
```

Output:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: This is an explanation of the problem, but doesn't answer the question. It actually answers the opposite (how to hide attributes), not how to find the hidden ones!

Comment: @RichL Actually it does. It shows that you have to check the metaclass chain to lookup for hidden attributes. Also I must add that it's not really possible to find hidden attributes in general since by using `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` you can easily generate attributes on the fly so even trying all attributes will not work since those methods can decide to make the attribute appear only at 13:37 of the day and not other times...