# Why aren't __mro__ and mro listed in the dir() of a class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Consider this piece of code:

```
class C:
    pass

print(C.mro())  # Output: [<class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>]
print(C.__mro__)  # Output: (<class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>)
print(dir(C))  # Output: too long :(
print("__mro__" in dir(C) or "mro" in dir(C))  # Output: False
```

If `mro` and `__mro__` are valid attributes of `C`, why don't they show up in the `dir()` function's output?

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663514/why-does-mro-not-show-up-in-dirmyclass) post and the accepted answer says it's because `__mro__` and `mro` are attributes of `type` which is the metaclass of `C` (meaning `C`'s class `object` is an instance of `type`) and not its superclass so `type`'s `__dict__` attribute isn't concatenated with the result of `dir(C)`. I still don't think `C` being an instance of `type` should cause `type`'s attribute `__mro__` to not be listed in `dir(C)`. To illustrate this, consider the following code:

```
class Sample:
    a = 5
    def f():
        pass

s = Sample()
print(dir(s))   # Output: too long
print("f" in dir(s))  # Output: True
print("a" in dir(s))  # Output: True
```

As you can see, `Sample` isn't `s`'s superclass, it's `s`'s type, so to speak, meaning `s` is an instance of `Sample` which is the same relationship that `C` from the previous code sample had to `type`. As you can see, the attributes of `Sample` are listed in `dir(s)`. So by this logic I would expect the attributes of `type` to also be listed in `dir(C)` but as we saw previously `__mro__` and `mro` are left out.

Can anybody shed some light on why this is?

Comment: `dir` isn't meant to be exhaustive. It tries to provide "interesting" attributes for a class. You aren't supposed to use it programmatically, so it isn't really productive to argue that something that *isn't* returned by `dir` *should* be, or even ask why isn't (because the answer isn't going to be much more interesting than "They didn't bother.").

Answer (score 1):

`dir(obj)` just calls `obj.__dir__`. For most objects, this will call `object.__dir__`, which collects attributes from `__dict__` and the type of the object.

[`type.__dir__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/56353b10023ff12c7c8d6288ae4bf7bdcd5d4b6c/Objects/typeobject.c#L5186-L5188) (Which is what is called when you call `dir(C)` or `dir(Sample)`) just happens to not collect attributes on the type of class (which will be `type` or whatever metaclass the class had).

If you call the "regular" `__dir__` on your class, you can see `mro`/`__mro__`:

```py
class C: pass
object.__dir__(C)  # => [..., '__mro__', ..., 'mro', ...]

class TypeWithoutDir(type): __dir__ = object.__dir__
class D(metaclass=TypeWithoutDir): pass
dir(D)  # => [..., '__mro__', ..., 'mro', ...]
```